# How do I make MSBuild work with a UWP solution generated from a Unity3D project?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, msbuild, uwp

So I'm trying to automate the process for building a packaged app from a Unity project and I've hit a roadblock when trying to use MSBuild to build the final app packages.
In Unity, when you build for UWP, a folder /UWP/ is generated for the project. These contain csharp projects for two .dlls that are required to build the uwp app.

For me, these dlls got generated in a folder for each platform (x86,x64, and ARM), but this is where I hit the roadblock. To build the app packages I use MSBuild(I've also tried with the Developer Command Prompt - same result) with the command.

```
MSBuild "{Project}.csproj" /p:Configuration=Debug;AppxBundle=Always;AppxBundlePlatforms="x64";OutputPath="AppxPackages"
```

This throws the error

> "C:\Users\{User}\Desktop\Output\{Project}\{Project}.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
>   (BeforeResolveReferences target) ->
>   C:\Users\{User}\Desktop\Output\{Project}\{Project}.csproj(319,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "{path-to-unity-project}\UWP\Assembly-CSharp\bin\AnyCPU\Debug\Unprocessed\Assembly-CSharp.dll" because it was not found.

What is happening here is that MSBuild is attempting to find a dll in a folder "AnyCPU" that simply does not exist.

Is there any way I could tell MSBuild to individually build each platform rather than look for a combined dll, or am I using MSBuild incorrectly?

Comment: So the two DLLs can successfully be built using the related project files, but you are having trouble generating the final app package, did I get that right? Is the app package built using a third project file or how is it supposed to work? Can you successfully generate the app package from Visual Studio?

Comment: Correct. The way Unity creates a UWP project is by generating two assembly projects called "Assembly-CSharp-firstpass" and "Assembly-CSharp" in a UWP directory. A third project at a location of your choosing is also generated. In my case .../Desktop/Output/... The third project has project references to both assembly projects. This project is also the one with the app manifest and all the UWP required files.  
I don't have any problems with making these packages through Visual Studio (Right click -> Store -> Create App Packages). The issue arises when trying to use MSBuild itself.

Comment: Have you try to build it under Release mode? Just the command line: MSBuild mysolution.sln  /p:Configuration=Release;AppxBundle=Always;AppxBundlePlatforms="x64"

Comment: I have tried as you suggested. Building under release seems to work. I am, however, confused by the content generated by this. Compared to using Visual Studio, there are a lot more files being generated. Visual Studio generates one appxbundle that supports all three platforms (x64, x86, and ARM) while MSBuild creates individual appxbundles for each. Is this standard behaviour? Maybe a property that I can set?

Comment: The property `AppxBundlePlatforms` is in plural, you can put multiple platforms in there like `AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64|ARM"`.

Comment: I understand that. I've also figured out what was confusing me: Using MSBuild generated mutiple .appx files (game_arm.appx, game_x64.appx, game_x86.appx, and a few more) while Visual Studio only generated a game_ARM_x64_x86.appxbundle. It just dawned on me that an appxbundle is a "zipped" version of all the three.

Comment: @Yamil, Since you have figured out what was confusing you, you can convert your comment to answer and mark it as answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I was unable to figure out why the Debug configuration looks for an assembly in the wrong directory, thanks to @Leo-MSFT I was able to fix the error that was occurring.

Firstly, I was calling MSBuild on the game project, this needed to be the generated solution instead.

Secondly, instead of using the Debug configuration, I used the Release configuration.

And finally, I was confused by the contents generated by the build compared to a build from Visual Studio (Right Click->Store->Create App Packages...). While VS generates an .appxbundle, using MSBuild will generate individually for each of the platforms selected such as game_x64.appx, game_ARM.appx, and a few more.

You can create the bundle yourself by using the [makeappx tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool).